# CertMgr.Exe to list information about a Certificate (by name) in a specific store

Tags: windows, batch-file, certificate-store

Is there anyway to list the information of a certificate (just one of them) by name? Or other uniqueidentifier?

The below works:

```
CertMgr.Exe -s My
```

The below works:

```
CertMgr.Exe -s -r localMachine My
```

The below does not work (but what I'm after):

```
CertMgr.Exe -s -r localMachine /n "My Certificate Name" My
```

Full Path as an FYI:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\CertMgr.Exe
```

Comment: If it did, the second statement would not work.

Comment: "-s  .   Indicate the store is a system store"......... (from /? command line) ....  It indicates the store "type", not the store name.